I need some advice about working as Mathematical Modeler/Data scientist
I have 10 years experience in studying mathematics in University, and I've just finished my Masters degree
I have some experience with LaTeX and Mathematica, what do I need to study to be able to pursue in a job such as mathematical modeling or data science? please note that I do understand that this may not be the perfect place to ask this question, but I don't know any other places at all, if you're not able to find an answer you can suggest me a place to ask this instead of just closing my question

If you have 10 years experience in studying mathematics... you should know what to do... start studying mathematical modeling / data science. Treat it as learning a new branch of mathematics, and do what you would normally do, start by picking up a book on the subject.

that's why I'm ASKING, it's easy to see a roadmap out there but they don't consider having a prior experience, so in my case, my specific case, what books can someone who already works in the field suggest for me? is there a tool that I need to learn how to use? @user2974951

See Data science / machine learning books for mathematicians. As for tools the safest bet is python.

My first exposure to data science / ML, coming from a pure statistics background, was a course by Andrew Ng on ML - that was about 10 years ago. The course still exist but it has changed since I took it. This might be a good place to start - it's on coursera.
